# Column into row

Tags: sql, pivot

I have table below

```
Product  Inventor
1        ROSE
1        EMMA
2        BEN
```

want result to be

```
PRODUCT INVENTOR1 INVENTOR2
1        ROSE      EMMA
2         BEN
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. What is your question, what is the problem, and where is your attempt at solving it?

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+pivot)

Answer (score 2):

What you are expecting/wanting will break normalisation. You should split this down further, so your tables look something like:

- products

  - product_id (PK)
  - product_name
- inventors

  - inventor_id (PK)
  - inventor_name
- inventor_product_link:

  - product_id (FK, composite key)
  - inventor_id (FK, composite key)

You can then link the same product to multiple inventors without breaking normalisation.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking out pandas.DataFrame.transpose: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Comment: This question doesn't have a Python tag. OP might not have access to run Python against their SQL environment.